# Boost Serialize binary data held in a void pointer

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a class 'SpecificTaskResults', children of abstract base class 'TaskResults', which holds a big chunk of data which is generated by some other classes

'SpecificTaskResults' holds a vector to some data, such as std::vector;
'TaskResults' holds a void* to the beginning of the data, and it's length.

```
class TaskResults
{
    public:
        void* _data;
        size_t _dataLength;

    private:
        void SetData(void* memAddr, size_t len)
        {
            _data = memAddr;
            _dataLength = len;
        }
}


class SpecificTaskResults : public TaskResults
{
    public:
        std::vector<float> _specificData;

        GiveData(std::vector<float> computedData)
        {
             _specificData = std::move(computedData);
             SetData(&_specificData[0], _specificData.size());
        }
}
```

The main purpose of the base class is to be able to save the data in binary format even when the base library does not know what exactly the data holds.

Now I need to serialize with Boost::Serialize this class to pass it to MPI, how can I correctly serialise the pointers in the base and derived class?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do `SpecificTaskResults::GiveData` save the same data twice? Once as a straight copy, and once as a pointer (if you used the address-of operator `&` correctly) to data that will disappear once the function returns (and with a length which is not correct as well)?

Comment: I had a couple of typos, which I now have fixed (the & operator to take the address, and I had forgot a move). The code comes from a scientific package that we use in our lab. Basically the base class is used internally by the library to handle saving to a custom format, checking for duplicate data, compression... while the derived class is used inside a plugin. There are multiple plugins, and each of them uses their own types internally, but all need the data to be stored the same way.